# Reference and call object issue?

Tags: javascript

I have a doubt about javascript references. So, if I have something like this:

```
a = function(){console.log('a')};
a['b'] = function(){console.log('b')}
```

Are these functions somehow related?

Comment: What `this` refers to depends on how the functions are called! In `a['b']()` `this` actually refers to `a`.

Comment: @Danilo: I've rolled back the changes. Questions on Stack Overflow are not meant to be moving targets. Once your question is asked and answered, fundamentally changing the question such that the answers no longer address the new question isn't how things are done here. If you have a follow-on question, post it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have *one* variable there: `a`. But you've created a *property* on the function `a` refers to, called `b`, that refers to another function.

That's the only relationship the two functions have: One is referenced by a property on the other. Other than that, they're unrelated.

As Unicode-art:

```
      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
a−−−−>|  (function)   |
      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
      | ...stuff...   |
      | length: 0     |     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
      | b             |−−−−>|  (function)   |
      +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+     +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                            | ...stuff...   |
                            | length: 0     |
                            +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
```

---

> ...with two different functions with this referring to window ?

As [deceze pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42787332/referrence-and-call-object-issue/42787427#comment72688793_42787332), the value of `this` within calls to those functions will depend entirely on how they're called, as with most JavaScript functions. (The exceptions being bound functions, which have a value for `this` bound to them, and ES2015+ arrow functions, which close over the `this` where they're defined.)

In loose mode, doing `a()` will indeed call the first function with `this` referring to the global object (which is the window object on browsers). In strict mode, `a()` would call it with `this` set to `undefined`. You can also use `a.call(anyValueHere)` to call it with `this` set to any value (in strict mode; in loose mode, `anyValueHere` has to be an object or you get that global object again). If you assign `a` to an object property (`var o = {a: a};`) then call it via `o.a()`, `this` within the call with equal `o`. If you do `new a`, the first function will be called with `this` referring to the new object from `new`. Etc.

In fact, with what you have in your question, `a.b()` would call the second function with `this` referring to the first function!

```js
var a = function(){console.log('a')};
a['b'] = function(){console.log("this is: ", this)}; // Note change
a.b();
```